# Displaying Twitter tweets on a webpage

Tags: twitter

I am aware that their are lots of plugins that allow you to do this but all the tutorials that say how to do this to get your tweets as plain text - hence being able to style them as you wish - will not work for me. Does anyone know how I can display tweets as plain text on a webpage for me to style them?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the Twitter API directly. For instance, https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=YOUR_SCREENNAME would return the timeline for **YOUR_SCREENNAME**.

**Note:** You're tweets can not be protected for this to work, and I also think this is only applicable in API v1.0, not v1.1.

See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Twitter REST API 1.1

For user timeline see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) the details.

If you are working with PHP you can use [this](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php) Simple PHP wrapper for the v1.1 API.

For .NET you can use this `LINQTOTWITTER`